# How to cache some temp data in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, caching, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, 10gen-csharp-driver

I have some client-server application. And as one of its part, I need to implement a paginal approach on client side. I am making data footprint from db *(I'm using MongoDB with 10gen's driver)* on server-side and then give part of the footprint on client's request.

I have a problem with storing the footprint. I can't store it on server as local variable, because it simply don't save any data after completing method. I figured out that the footprint data can be stored as a MongoDB cache. But I don't know how it works.

Googling didn't made any progress for me. So can anybody explain me how to implement this MongoDB caching in C#?

Comment: You could save those footprints to another collection in mongodb

Comment: I'm currently unable to change db structure, but if it'll the only possibility I'll try to get permission to do that.

Comment: By the way, how unnecessary data will be removed? Manually only?

Comment: or via background job. MongoDB does not delete data for you at the moment (AFAIK).

Comment: Ok, I'll consider this as a fallback if there won't be another options. Thanks.

Comment: MongoDB is fast enough to serve as a caching server.  I would suggest, as Sergio has, to store the footprint data in another collection or db in mongodb so you only need to use a single technology.  Alternatively, you can always use the built-in ASP.NET cache or another tech (memcache, AppFabric, etc...)

Comment: Thanks, Craig. It seems to be the easiest way to do what I need. However, it makes some bureaucratic obstacles for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Sergio's and Craig's answers in comments to my question I assume that easiest way "to cache" some data in MongoDB is to create separate collection for storing data. Or (if it's not an option, as in my case) to use built-in ASP.NET cache.